# drush cr hanging

Tags: 10

I have three instances of Drupal 10.1 running in kubernetes all with similar code bases. On two of the instances `drush cr` works fine, but on the third `drush cr` hangs forever. All three instances are using the same redis instance. All three are using drush 11.6.0.

I've tried clearing each cache bin separately using drush cc, and that works fine.

I'm guessing the problem is something in the database because that's the only thing really different, but I'm not sure how to track it down. I tried using -vvv on drush but it doesn't give much helpful:

```
 [info] Starting bootstrap to site [0.08 sec, 18.5 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase 2 [0.08 sec, 18.51 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2 [0.08 sec, 18.51 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2 [0.08 sec, 18.51 MB]
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2 [0.08 sec, 18.51 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.08 sec, 18.51 MB]
 [info] Change working directory to /var/www/web [0.08 sec, 18.51 MB]
 [info] Initialized Drupal 10.1.5 root directory at /var/www/web [0.08 sec, 18.55 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2 [0.08 sec, 18.55 MB]
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2 [0.09 sec, 19 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.09 sec, 19 MB]
 [debug] Could not find a Drush config file at sites/default/drush.yml. [0.09 sec, 19.23 MB]
 [info] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.09 sec, 19.23 MB]
```

Comment: Maybe it's the database. I don't think there is enough information here to provide an answer. This could be on of those `max_allowed_packet` questions: https://www.drupal.org/node/259580

Comment: All three instances have the same mariadb config. The weird thing is it never times out. I've had it running now for 2 hours and it's still just sitting there.

Comment: Tell me you have checked the mariadb error logs.

Comment: Yes, no errors. All three drupal instances are pointing at the same RDS mariadb instance (different database schemas within that instance)

Comment: It finally completed:  [success] Cache rebuild complete. [14396.96 sec, 79.12 MB] (that's almost 4 hours)